# Implicit conversion insists on using private function

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a class that has a conversion operator to `int&` that I want to hide. I created a derived class that only offers a conversion to `int` and made the conversion to `int&` private. But I still cannot make the `int` conversion to be used, either the compiler tells me that the conversion is ambiguous, or insists to use the `int&` conversion and tells me it is inaccessible. How do I make this work?

```
struct Base {
    int value;
    operator int&() { return value; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    operator int() { return operator int&(); }

   private:
    using Base::operator int&;
};

int main() {
    int p = Derived();
}
```

P.S. The compiler uses gcc 9.3.0, and the real case is the wrapping of XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue class from [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp) to handle probable conversion from double XmlRpcValue type to int or int XmlRpcValue type to double.

Comment: `private` doesn't cause the existence of `operator int &()` to be ignored.   The compiler picks the candidates (`operator int()` and `operator int &()`) and determines which is best BEFORE it checks for accessibility (e.g. `private`).     The two candidates are equally viable, so ambiguity is detected.    The solution is to remove one of the operators.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Peter. Unfortunately I don't have access to the Base class code. Is there any way I could hide the operator while still inheriting the class? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter: unfortunately, I tried a little and could not find a way to remove an operator declared on a base class from a derived one.

Comment: Rather than using inheritance, make `Base` a `private` member of `Derived`.   Then there is no `operator int &()` in the interface of `Derived` unless you specify one.

Comment: Oh alright, then I guess there are no other solution than to compose the Base class rather than to inherit it. Thank you guys for your help. (though I don't know if this behavior is deliberate and intended by the compiler team)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way through inheritance. But if *containment* is an option (`Derived` *has a* `Base` instead of *is a*), it is much simpler:

```
struct Base {
    int value;
    operator int&() { return value; }
};

struct Derived{
    Base b;
    operator int() { return b.operator int&(); }

};

int main() {
    int p = Derived();
}
```

The main drawback is that you will have to use explicit delegation for the methods/members you want to offer in `Derived`

Comment: Yes, my current solution is like this, but the base class that I want to wrap contains many functions so I'd very much like to avoid the drawback that you said in your answer. Thank you very much for your answer anyway Serge!

Comment: @BimoAdityarahman: Maybe you could unaccept my answer for a while to see whether others can find *the* trick. C++ is a very complex language when we go into its corner cases. I am good at *real world* programming in C++ but I do not pretend to be an expert in the intricacies of the language...